# CLIPS re run the entire program automatically

Tags: clips

I have a program in CLIPS that when it starts ask the user for some inputs. I want when is no other rule to execute and finished to run again automatically the (initial-fact). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a rule with a lower salience than all other rules that issues a reset command.

```
(defrule restart
   (declare (salience -1000))
   =>
   (reset))
```